# Mysql collation error on laravel query, related to search parameter

Tags: mysql, laravel, collation

My search query has `COLLATE utf8mb4_bin` which is necessary to differentiate between european characters and non-european character, for example `a` vs `ä`.

If I run the query with hard coded search term, it works in phpmyadmin, and it works on this fiddle: [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4kXT5Kf6D8hdD9bigghhuc/4). You can see that the table has `CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.

But on this other fiddle site ( [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d8b9899/1)), the same query gives the error:

```
COLLATION 'utf8mb4_bin' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
```

And in **laravel**, if I run the query with hard coded search term, it works without error, but if I use a parameter I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1253 COLLATION 'utf8mb4_bin' is not 
valid for CHARACTER SET 'binary'
```

So it is very strange. Here is the laravel query with bound parameters which produces the above error:

```
$query_events = "SELECT e.id, e.title, e.location,e.event_at, e.content as content, 
e.limited_participants,e.max_participants,associations.name, 
     CONCAT(:url,'/events/', e.id) AS permalink, 
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM event_participants evp WHERE evp.event_id = e.id) 
             AS participants
        FROM events AS e
        LEFT JOIN associations ON e.association_id = associations.id  
        WHERE CONCAT(e.title ,e.location ,e.content ,associations.name ) 
               LIKE :search
           COLLATE utf8mb4_bin
           ORDER BY e.event_at 
           DESC
           LIMIT 5";

        $results['events'] = DB::select($query_events,[ 
            'url'       =>   $url,
            'search'    =>   '%' . $search . '%'
        ]);
```

If I remove `COLLATE utf8mb4_bin`, there is no error but european/non-eurpoean letters are mixed up in the search results. If I hard code some search parameter (like in the fiddles) and comment out the 'search' property in the array, the query works as it should, giving the right results.

I use xampp and the mysql version is 5.7.22 according to phpmyadmin.

So I need to use that collation and need to be able to use a search parameter, but how do I avoid this error??

Answer (score 0):

Plan A: Preface the query with

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4;
```

Plan B:  change the `CHARACTER SET` of the literal:

```
LIKE _utf8mb4"%oteborg%"
```

Comment: I don't know how to add it to the query, this caused syntax error: $query_events = "SET NAMES utf8mb4; SELECT e.id.... Plan B also caused syntax error,  I tried: "LIKE _utf8mb4 :search ".

Comment: Run it as a _separate_ query _once_ after connecting (and before any `SELECTs` that need it.